# I can't get data from the dropdown fields in embedded forms of Mailchimp

Tags: forms, mailchimp

My code is below.

So, I'd like to have an embedded form on my website, but I can't get the dropdown to work and send me the data inputted. Please help.

```
<div class="mc-field-group"><label for="mce-undefined">Contact purpose </label><select class="" id="mce-undefined">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="More information">More information</option>
            <option value="Quotation request">Quotation request</option>
            <option value="Technical Data Sheet request">Technical Data Sheet request</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select></div>
```

I tried to create an embedded form and I was expecting all inputs to be sent to me.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. What happens in your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and it appears to a bug in how Mailchimp is generating the HTML for a dropdown field. The id generated for the select tag ("mce-undefined") is wrong and it should also have a name attribute. You can work around the issue by manually changing the HTML.

First you'll need the name of the merge tag for the dropdown field. In Mailchimp go to Audience->Settings->Audience Fields and *|MERGE|* tags. Find the merge tag in the "Put this tag in your content:" column. I've used the custom tag name, but the default ones may work too. You just want the name without the *||*.

If the tag name is, say, PURPOSE, change the code to:

```
<div class="mc-field-group">
    <label for="mce-PURPOSE">Contact purpose </label><select class="" id="mce-PURPOSE" name="PURPOSE">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="More information">More information</option>
        <option value="Quotation request">Quotation request</option>
        <option value="Technical Data Sheet request">Technical Data Sheet request</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
      </select></div>
```

where I've changed the for attribute of the label and the id of the select to "mce-PURPOSE" and added the name attribute to the select with value "PURPOSE".